# Difference between Firefox on Mac and Windows

Tags: css, firefox, rendering

I have some problems with a website which renders differently (CSS) with Firefox on Windows and Mac. I've googled if there are any differences in the CSS rendering on Mac Firefox and PC Firefox, but it looks like there shouldn't. Does someone know if there are any differences between Firefox on Mac and Windows, even if it's the same version of Firefox?

Here is the page I'm talking about... the problem is with the vertical centering with the pseudo-elemente ::before

http://tinyurl.com/l6w6c9w

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the problem: I had an inline-block element set to width: 100%. And somehow on windows there was a "whitespace" after the 100%-inline-block. On Mac, there was no white-space after that element.